# Read Wireshark file

Tags: c#

i want to build application who send packets, i know SharpPcap and Pcap.Net but want to build from my own.
the first thing that i want to start with is open Wireshark file but unlike SharpPcap and Pcap.Net i want my application to have the ability to handle all Wireshark file not only pcap files.
i am a new developer and don't know even where to start so forgive me for not post here what i have try.
the only thing i have try is BinaryReader that read my file and got only strange characters.
i'd like any help that can lead me to learn hot to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at Pcap.Net implementation and find out how they do it.

Comment: i don't think this is open source

Comment: http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/ - looks pretty opensource to me